# Fetch all rows data from second table using single join query

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into a 1-N situation. i.e 1 record in 1st table will have multiple records in second table, I just wanna fetch all data corresponding to the ID in 1st table using joins, is this possible.

```
table 1 :  ID  name
            1   pradeep

table 2:   ID table1_id   orders
           1   1           23
           2   1           25
           3   1           26
```

In a single query i should get all records. I don't wanna loop as i am doing it and its taking lot of time.

I want to display user html output in manner like this. So there lies the problem.

```
ID Name orders1 orders2 orders order4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t2.* /* fetch data from second table */
FROM 
    table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = <id>;
```

I wouldn't recomment it though. Why don't you just run it as 2 separate queries?

Comment: it will work but the number of records as output will become more i guess. Am i right.

Comment: @pradeep more than what? I see you are being suspicious about running 2 queries? `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = <id>` query will retreive all the information you want. How there'll be more rows then needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table2 
LEFT JOIN 
  table1 ON 
    table1.ID = table2.table1_id
```